# Tray Icon not diplaying the Image in Visual c++

Tags: c++, c

I am working in Visual Studio 2010. I am creating a simple application which shows the icon in the tray(taskbar). the problem i am facing is the application is shown in the tray(taskbar), but its icon is not shown. My code is given below

```
    NOTIFYICONDATA nid; 
nid.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
nid.hWnd = hWnd;
nid.uID = 100;
nid.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION;
nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_MYMESSAGE;
nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL,  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON2));
//nid.hIcon =(HICON) hIcon;
wcscpy_s(nid.szTip, L"ultraDefender");
nid.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE NIF_ICON NIF_TIP;
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
```

Kindly guide me

Comment: I think your LoadIcon() call is wrong: `LoadIcon(NULL)` is only supposed to work for standard icons; for yours you need the HINSTANCE or HMODULE of the EXE or DLL that contains the icon.

Comment: but even the standard icons are not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should zero out the structure before filling it in... there are other members that you're not using where non-zero values will impact your results:

```
NOTIFYICONDATA nid;
ZeroMemory( &nid, sizeof(nid) );
...
```

additionally as *noz* says, your flags need to be or'd:

```
nid.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
```

Comment: nid.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP; arise a Syntax error Expression is expected

Answer (score 2):

```
nid.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE NIF_ICON NIF_TIP;
```

should be

```
nid.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
```

Also,

```
MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON2)
```

should be

```
IDI_ICON2
```

if this is the name of the icon

Comment: nid.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
arise a Syntax error Expression is expected